# Node.js and TypeScript with promise

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to setup a simple project to learn Node.js and TypeScript. Below is my package.json file:

```js
{
  "name": "ES6-TypeScript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^2.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/es6-collections": "^0.5.31",
    "@types/es6-promise": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/node": "^9.4.7"
  }
}
```

And below is my tsconfig.json file:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
        "es2016",
        "dom","es2015.promise"
    ],
         "types": ["node"],
         "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
         ],
         "moduleResolution": "node",
    }
}
```

If I try to use Map, Set or Promise I am getting errors like below:

`error TS2552: Cannot find name 'Map'. Did you mean 'map'?
error TS2552: Cannot find name 'Set'. Did you mean 'set'?
error TS2552: Cannot find name 'Set'. Did you mean 'set'?`

I do have a setup where I use gulp to transpile ts, scss, css files and all. But I am trying to setup a simple project without any build system just to quickly test ES6 features with typescript and node without the need of browsers.

My node version is 8.6.0.

Directory Structure:

[image]

map-set.ts file :

```js
let map = new Map();
map.set("A",1);
map.set("B",2);
map.set("C",3);
console.log('-----------MAP----------');
console.log(map.get("A"));
console.log(`Is A in map ${map.has("A")}`);
console.log(`Map Size: ${map.size}`);

let map2 = new Map([
  ["Apple",1],
  ["ORANGE",2],
  ["MANGO",3]
]);
for(let key of map2.keys()) {
  console.log(key);
}

for(let value of map2.values()){
  console.log(value);
}

for(let entry of map2.entries()) {
  console.log(`${entry[0]} -> ${entry[1]}`);
}

for(let [key, value] of map2.entries()) {
  console.log(`${key} -> ${value}`);
}


console.log('-----------SET----------');
let set = new Set();
set.add('Benz');
set.add('Bentley');
set.add('BMW');
for(let entry of set) {
  console.log(entry);
}
```

promise-example.ts file

```js
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

});
```

Can anybody help me in setting up a ts-node.js project to explore ES6 features.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: how are you testing output? show your `.ts` file

Comment: How are you running the TypeScript compiler and what does your directory structure look like?

Comment: I am using tsc filename.ts to test

Comment: I have updated my question with Directory Structure and my example.ts files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to run typescript file is,

Install and it will run your es6 features like a charm
`npm install @types/es6-shim`

Install TypeScript globally with NPM,

```
npm install typescript -g
```

Then run your `example.ts` file with,

```
tsc example
```

If you are looking for more options with `tsc` visit [compiler-options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Comment: after installing @types/es6-shim those errors did go. But the code ```let map2 = new Map([
  ["Apple",1],
  ["ORANGE",2],
  ["MANGO",3]
]);
for(let key of map2.keys()) {
  console.log(key);
}``` is giving error error TS2345: Argument of type '(string | number)[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ForEachable<[{}, {}]>'. Any Idea why?

Comment: I tried ```let map2 = new Map<string, number>([
  ["Apple",1]]); ```. Types of property 'forEach' are incompatible. Type '(callbackfn: (value: (string | number)[], index: number, array: (string | number)[][]) => void, t...' is not assignable to type '(callbackfn: (value: [string, number]) => void) => void'. Types of parameters 'callbackfn' and 'callbackfn' are incompatible. Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible. Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type '[string, number]'.Property '0' is missing in type '(string | number)[]'.

Comment: @AbhilashDK give me some time i need to look into it

Comment: Thank You. Even I am trying to find out. Will keep looking. When I searched I got somebody pointing out to add generic parameters. Still got the same error.